# WPF MVVM Change View after sign in/out (ICommand execution)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, command

recently I've been working on a WPF app and I have some problems making the view to change after successful login from LoginViewModel.

**BaseViewModel.cs** -> tied with MainWindow

```
class BaseViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    public DelegateCommand HomeViewCommand { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand GroupViewCommand { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand UserViewCommand { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand LoginViewCommand { get; set; }

    public HomeViewModel HomeVM { get; set; }
    public GroupViewModel GroupVM { get; set; }
    public UserViewModel UserVM { get; set; }
    public LoginViewModel LoginVM { get; set; }

    private AppUser _signedUser;
    public AppUser SignedUser
    {
        get { return _signedUser; }
        set { _signedUser = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private object _currentView;
    public object CurrentView
    {
        get { return _currentView; }
        set { _currentView = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public BaseViewModel()
    {
        HomeVM = new HomeViewModel();
        GroupVM = new GroupViewModel();
        UserVM = new UserViewModel();
        LoginVM = new LoginViewModel();
        
        CurrentView = LoginVM;

        GroupViewCommand = new DelegateCommand(o =>
        {
            CurrentView = GroupVM;
        });

        UserViewCommand = new DelegateCommand(o =>
        {
            CurrentView = UserVM;
        });

        HomeViewCommand = new DelegateCommand(o =>
        {
            CurrentView = HomeVM;
        });

        SignedUser = AppUser.Instance;
    }
}
```

**LoginViewModel.cs** -> there's a button bound to SignFlow in the view

```
class LoginViewModel
{
    public SignInCommand SignFlow { get; }

    public LoginViewModel()
    {
        SignFlow = new SignInCommand();
    }
}
```

**SignInCommand.cs**

```
public class SignInCommand : CommandBase
{
    public bool IsLoggedIn;

    public override void Execute(object? parameter)
    {
        CacheCheck();

        if (IsLoggedIn)
        {
            SignOut();
        }
        else
        {
            SignIn();
        }
    }
//Rest of the code for API call, token check etc.
```

I've tried to implement a LoginSuccessful Event as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63487083/wpf-c-sharp-how-can-i-switch-to-dashboard-view-after-successfull-login-attemp-h) but I can't get it to work as in my case the Login is being fired from SignInCommand instead of being a part of LoginViewModel.

Is there a way for me to invoke that view change in SignInCommand.cs?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the `SignInCommand` with a reference to the `LoginViewModel` or the type where the method is defined:

```
class LoginViewModel
{
    public SignInCommand SignFlow { get; }

    public LoginViewModel()
    {
        SignFlow = new SignInCommand(this);
    }

    public void SignIn()
    {
        //...
    }

    public void SignOut()
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class SignInCommand : CommandBase
{
    private readonly LoginViewModel _loginViewModel;
    public bool IsLoggedIn;

    public SignInCommand(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
    {
        _loginViewModel = loginViewModel;
    }

    public override void Execute(object? parameter)
    {
        CacheCheck();

        if (IsLoggedIn)
        {
            _loginViewModel.SignOut();
        }
        else
        {
            _loginViewModel.SignIn();
        }
    }
}
```